# запрос на две таблицы

Tags: sql

Как написать запрос, вытягивающий данные с двух таблиц?
Покажу на своем примере.

- Есть таблица `A_NumberPlan` с некоторыми столбцами. Нас интересует столбец `Prefix`.
- Есть таблица `A_RuleRecords`. Нас там также интересует один столбец - `Account`.
- И есть некая переменная входящая, пусть `@phone`.

Суть запроса.
Если значение переменной `phone` есть в заголовке `Prefix`, то в переменную ( пусть `@phone2`) занести значение из `Account`.
Эти две таблицы связаны между собой в графическом редакторе.

Т.е.
Есть номер `999` (`Prefix`), ему соответствует номер `666` (`Account`).
Надеюсь, понятно объяснил.

**UPD**: Если все таки непонятно.

- Есть входящий звонок. Номер у него `999`.
- В таблице `A_NumberPlan` столбец `Prefix = 999`.
- В другой таблице для этого номера соответствует `666`. `A_RuleRecords`, `Account = 666`.

Суть запроса

```
select (account), @phone2
from [A_RuleRecords]
```

и дальше не знаю, как связать с данными из первой таблицы
но представляю, что

```
from [A_NumberPlan]
where (prefix) = @phone1
```

Comment: не совсем понятно

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко обновил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите join и left outer join в спецификации SQL.

```
select table1.col1, table2.col2 
from table1 
join table2 on table2.id=table1.id_from_table2
```

и

```
   select table1.col1, table2.col2 
    from table1 left outer join table2 
    on table2.id=table1.id_from_table2
```

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29